# Question about editing mates using a Macro in Solidworks

Tags: c#, vba, solidworks, solidworksapi

I need help to fix a problem that I encounter while assembly in macro. One of the parts that I want to assembly formerly assembled as anti-aligned relative to the top plane. The problem is that when I use the anti-aligned part and a new part for assembly, the macro automatically assembling the two of them as aligned. For this reason, trouble occurs on dimensions. How can I see and change as anti-aligned on macro. Also I want to be able to change the alignment measure. What is the thing that I need to change?  By the way, there are about 5000 of the anti-aligned parts I mentioned above, because of this reason I can not change that parts.

I put my assembly code below.

```
boolstatus = Part.Extension.SelectByID2("Üst Düzlem", "PLANE", 0, 0, 0, False, 0, Nothing, 0)
boolstatus = Part.Extension.SelectByID2(Cells(volki, 9), "PLANE", 0, 0, 0, True, 0, Nothing, 0)
Set matefeature = swAssembly.AddMate5(swMateType_e.swMateCOINCIDENT, swMateAlign_e.swMateAlignALIGNED, False, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, False, False, 0, 1)
boolstatus = Part.EditRebuild3()
boolstatus = Part.Extension.SelectByID2("Sağ Düzlem", "PLANE", 0, 0, 0, True, 0, Nothing, 0)
boolstatus = Part.Extension.SelectByID2(Cells(volki, 10), "PLANE", 0, 0, 0, True, 0, Nothing, 0)
Set matefeature = swAssembly.AddMate5(swMateType_e.swMateCOINCIDENT, swMateAlign_e.swMateAlignALIGNED, False, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, False, False, 0, 1)
boolstatus = Part.EditRebuild3()
boolstatus = Part.Extension.SelectByID2("OnEgalizePlane", "PLANE", 0, 0, 0, True, 0, Nothing, 0)
boolstatus = Part.Extension.SelectByID2(Cells(volki, 11), "PLANE", 0, 0, 0, True, 0, Nothing, 0)
Set matefeature = swAssembly.AddDistanceMate(2, False, Cells(volki, 17), 0, 0, 1, 1, 1)
boolstatus = Part.EditRebuild3()
```

Answer (score 0):

If the anti-align is about AddMate5, you just neeed to change swMateAlign_e.swMateAlignALIGNED by swMateAlign_e.swMateAlignANTI_ALIGNED

As for the dimension you can use:

```
Set MateFeature = swAssembly.AddDistanceMate(swMateAlign_e.swMateAlignALIGNED, False, Cells(volki, 17), Cells(volki, 17), Cells(volki, 17), 1, 1, Empty)
or:
Set MateFeature = swAssembly.AddDistanceMate(swMateAlign_e.swMateAlignANTI_ALIGNED, False, Cells(volki, 17), Cells(volki, 17), Cells(volki, 17), 1, 1, Empty)
```